# Java función de métodos, herencia, objetos

Tags: java

En java función

```
public boolean getTieneSombrero
```

hacer el get y el set y un `@override`

Introducir el código aquí y hacer  que te devuelva que si la persona tiene sombrero te imprima si o no, depende del resultado.

Yo cuando lo hago me sale `false` o `null` pero no me sale , ni `true`, ni `false`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar lo que hiciste? asi sabemos que error cometiste y que deberias corregir ;)

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy vaga, puedes poner la estructura de la clase donde tienes ese metodo para asi poder ayudarte, para saber que tipo de variable es el sombrero etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que tienes algo así, te dejo los métodos que solicitaste. Espero te ayude. Un saludo

```
public class Persona 
{
    private boolean sombrero;

    Persona()
    {
        //Por defecto la persona no tiene sombrero
        this.sombrero=false;
    }

    //Metodo para decirte si tiene o no sombrero la persona
    public boolean getTieneSombrero()
    {
        if(this.sombrero==true)
        {
            //Tiene sombrero
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //No tiene sombrero
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Metodo para poner o quitarlse el sombrero a la persona, si le pasas true tendra, si le pasas false no tendra
    public void setSombrero(boolean sombrero)
    {
        this.sombrero=sombrero;
    }

}
```

Comment: En los casos en que las preguntas son ejercicios o tareas, pedimos siempre que quien pregunta muestre algo de lo que hizo, para demostrar que lo intento y llego a un error puntual. Resolverle el ejercicio no ayuda a que aprenda, porque solo copian el resultado y no saben que hicieron.